# Eric Martin's SimpleModal

Tags: jquery

I have a problem with my implementation and understanding of Eric Martin's SimpleModal jQuery plugin. I've already read the other answers here and the plugin info pages.

Here's my function:

```
function generate_modal_div(arg_1_image, arg_2_title) {
  $('<img src="' + arg_1_image + '"/>'); // preload image - does not remedy
  $('#basic-modal-content').html('<img src="' + arg_1_image + '" alt="thumbnail"/>' + '<p>' + arg_2_title + '</p>' + '<a class="prev browse left"></a><a class="next browse right"></a></div>');
};
```

How do I add the options parameters to this method. Please help, I just don't understand!

Comment: Don't use back ticks (\`) to denote code blocks. Instead, indent by 4 spaces. The back ticks are reserved for inline code statements, `like this`.

Comment: Thanks djikay, apologies for the faux pas.